# Want to update Object using index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

This is my code

I updated whole code here for more reference .
I handled Dynamic inputs

```
      <style type="text/css">

          #navPrev, #navNext {
            color: #333;
            font-size: 1em;
          }

          #navPrev:hover, #navNext:hover {
            color: #1abb9c;
          }

          #navPrev[disabled], #navNext[disabled] {
            color: #cdcdcd;
            cursor: default;
          }

          .createborder {
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding-top: 16px;
          }
          .removeborder {
            border: 0px solid;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding-top: 16px;
          }
      </style>
      <div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12">

               <div class="row">
               <div id="fieldallow"></div>
               </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="navPrev" onclick="prevImg()">Prev</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="navNext" onclick="nextImg()">Next</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="page-wrapper" class="border-cnttp">
    <div class="right-panel">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in errorshow" role="alert" style="display: none;">
      <button type="button" class="close close_alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      <span class="error_message"></span>
    </div>
      <div class="content-main fade-in-cnt">

      <div class="panel panel-default AllMenuList">
          <div class="panel-heading f-panel-head"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo ADDCLIENTXML; ?>

          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
             <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div class="form-group frm-grpmrgn">
                <div class="row">
                 <form role="form" id="Menu_details" name="Menu_details" method="post" class="row">
                    <div class="form-group frm-padbtm col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="desc"><span class="fheadcolor">Client </span><span style="color:red;"> * </span></label>
                        <select name="mclient" id="mclient" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control bs-select-hidden project adminselect" data-live-search="true" onchange="changeclient(this.value);"><?php echo $clientlist; ?></select>
                        <p class="form-error mclient"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group frm-padbtm col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="desc"><span class="fheadcolor">Template </span><span style="color:red;"> * </span></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" id="mtemplate" name="mtemplate" class="form-control" value="" readonly="true">
                        <p class="form-error mtemplate"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group frm-padbtm col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                      <label for="name"><span class="fheadcolor">No.of Tabs </span><span style="color:red;"> * </span></label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="" id="mtabs" name="mtabs" class="form-control" value="3" readonly="true">
                      <p class="form-error mtabs"></p>
                    </div>
                 </form>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">PO Metadata</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Order Values</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">PO Summary</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h4>PO Metadata</h4>
      <div class="form-group frm-padbtm col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <label for="name"><span class="fheadcolor">Enter Inputs</span><span style="color:red;"> * </span></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" id="selectinput1" name="selectinput1" class="form-control" value="" min="1"><br>
        <button type="button" id="selectinputbtn1" class="btn btn-info" value="submit">Create Input</button>
        <p class="form-error mtabs"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group frm-padbtm col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="generateinputs"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h4>Order Values</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h4>PO Summary</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>


    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var data;
 var inputobjarr = {};
     $("#template_add").on("click",function(){
      location.href = "index.php?rt=xmlconfig/addxmltemp/0";
    });

     function changeclient(val)
     {

        var clientid = val;

        $.ajax({ 
          url: "?rt=xmlconfig/gettemplates",
          type: 'post',
          dataType: "json",
          data:{clientid:clientid}, 
          success: function(response)
          {
              var counttemplate = parseInt(response) + 1;
              $("#mtemplate").val(counttemplate);
          }
        });

     }
     $('#selectinput1').bind('keyup paste', function(){
        this.value = $(this).val();
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
     });
     $('#selectinputbtn1').on('click', function(){
        $("#generateinputs").addClass('createborder');
        var columnObjArr = [];

        this.value = $("#selectinput1").val();

        if(this.value!='')
        {


          $('#generateinputs').html("");
          var num = $("#selectinput1").val(),
              cur = $('div.rmv input:text'),
              curL = cur.length;
          if (!curL) {
              for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                attributesetup(inputobjarr);
                columnObjArr.push({id:i,inputobjarr});
                  $(makeRow(i)).appendTo($('#generateinputs'));
              }
          }
          else if (num < curL) {
              var filled = cur.filter(

              function() {
                  return $("#selectinput1").val().length
              }),
                  empties = curL - filled.length,
                  dA = curL - num;

              if (empties >= num) {
                  cur.filter(

                  function() {
                      return !$("#selectinput1").val().length
                  }).parent().slice(-num).remove();
              }
              else if (empties < num) {
                  var remainder = num - empties;

                  cur.filter(

                  function() {
                      return !$("#selectinput1").val().length
                  }).parent().slice(-num).remove();
                  $('div.rmv').slice(-remainder).remove();
              }
          }
          else {
              var diff = num - curL;

              for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
                  $(makeRow(i)).appendTo($('#generateinputs'));
              }
          }

        }
        else{
          $('#generateinputs').html("");
        }

        data = columnObjArr;
        console.log(data.toSource())

  });

     function attributesetup(inputobjarr)
     {

         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo ACCORDIANID; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo ACCORDIANID; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo ACCORDIANID; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo PARENTDIVCLASS; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo PARENTDIVCLASS; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo PARENTDIVCLASS; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo DIV_TYPE; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo DIV_TYPE; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo DIV_TYPE; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo LABELNAME_CLASS; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo LABELNAME_CLASS; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo LABELNAME_CLASS; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo LABELNAME; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo LABELNAME; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo LABELNAME; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo TABLEROWHIDEFLAG; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo TABLEROWHIDEFLAG; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo TABLEROWHIDEFLAG; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo TABLEROWHIDEID; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo TABLEROWHIDEID; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo TABLEROWHIDEID; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo MANITORY; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo MANITORY; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo MANITORY; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo MULTIPLEINPUT; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo MULTIPLEINPUT; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo MULTIPLEINPUT; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo DIV_STATUS; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo DIV_STATUS; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo DIV_STATUS; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo DBACCESS; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo DBACCESS; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo DBACCESS; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo INPUTS_TYPE; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo INPUTS_TYPE; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo INPUTS_TYPE; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo INPUT_CONTROLNAME; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo INPUT_CONTROLNAME; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo INPUT_CONTROLNAME; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo INPUT_CLASS; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo INPUT_CLASS; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo INPUT_CLASS; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo FIELD_CLASS; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo FIELD_CLASS; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo FIELD_CLASS; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo POSTID; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo POSTID; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo POSTID; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo POSTNAME; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo POSTNAME; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo POSTNAME; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo INPUT_MANITORY; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo INPUT_MANITORY; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo INPUT_MANITORY; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo READONLY; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo READONLY; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo READONLY; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo MULTISELECT; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo MULTISELECT; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo MULTISELECT; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo CHARVALIDATE; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo CHARVALIDATE; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo CHARVALIDATE; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo NUMERICVALIDATE; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo NUMERICVALIDATE; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo NUMERICVALIDATE; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo BODYONLOAD; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo BODYONLOAD; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo BODYONLOAD; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo JSONARRAYNAME; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo JSONARRAYNAME; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo JSONARRAYNAME; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo DEFAULTFLAG; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo DEFAULTFLAG; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo DEFAULTFLAG; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo DEFAULTVALUE; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo DEFAULTVALUE; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo DEFAULTVALUE; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo OPTIONVALUE; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo OPTIONVALUE; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo OPTIONVALUE; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo DBTABLERUNID; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo DBTABLERUNID; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo DBTABLERUNID; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo DBTABLENAME; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo DBTABLENAME; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo DBTABLENAME; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo DBCOLUMNNAME; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo DBCOLUMNNAME; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo DBCOLUMNNAME; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo CHARALLOWFLAG; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo CHARALLOWFLAG; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo CHARALLOWFLAG; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo CHARALLOWLEN; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo CHARALLOWLEN; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo CHARALLOWLEN; ?>");
         inputobjarr[attr('<?php echo PLACEHOLDER; ?>')] = attr('<?php echo PLACEHOLDER; ?>')+'||'+attrvalue("<?php echo PLACEHOLDER; ?>");

     }

     function attr(valattr)
     {
       var values = valattr.split('||');

       return values[0];
     }
     function attrvalue(attrval)
     {
       var values = attrval.split('||');

       return values[1];
     }
     function makeRow(cnt) {
       var div = document.createElement('div'),
        button = document.createElement('button'),
        a = document.createElement('a'),
        btntxt = document.createTextNode('input'+cnt),
        t = document.createElement('i');
    div.className = 'form-group frm-padbtm col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 rmv';
    button.type = 'button';
    button.className = "btn btn-primary";
    button.value = 'input';
    button.setAttribute('onclick', "openModal("+parseInt(cnt)+")");
    button.appendChild(btntxt);
    t.className = 'fa fa-close';
    t.setAttribute('style','color:red;')
    a.href = 'javascript:;';
    a.className = 'remScnt';
    a.appendChild(t);
    div.appendChild(button);
    div.insertBefore(a, button.nextSibling);

    return div;
}




$('body').on('click', '.rmv a.remScnt', function() {
    var updateselectinput = $("#selectinput1").val();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var updtval = parseInt(updateselectinput) - 1;
    $("#selectinput1").val(updtval);
});

$("body").on('keyup','.getupdateinputs',function(e)
{ 
    var inputid = $(this).attr('data-knownid');
    var nametochange = $(this).attr('id');
    var changevalue = this.value;

    var matchid = parseInt(inputid) - 1;
   var index = data.findIndex(function(data) {
          return data.id == inputid
        });

    if(index == matchid)
    {
     $(data).eq(index)[0].inputobjarr[nametochange] = nametochange+'||'+changevalue; 

    }



})

var currentItem = 1;

function prevImg() {

  if (currentItem > 1) {
    currentItem--;
  }
  loadData();
}

function nextImg() {

console.log(data)

  if (currentItem < data.length) {
    currentItem++;
  }
  loadData();

}

function loadData() {
  var buildfields = '';

  $("#modalTitle").html('Input '+currentItem);

  var jsonfrmt = data[currentItem - 1];

jsonfrmt = jsonfrmt.inputobjarr;

  Object.keys(jsonfrmt).map(function(e) {
    var fieldseperate = jsonfrmt[e].split('||');

    buildfields+='<div class="form-group frm-padbtm col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><label for="name"><span class="fheadcolor">'+fieldseperate[0]+'</span><span style="color:red;"> * </span></label><input type="text" placeholder="" id="'+fieldseperate[0]+'" name="'+fieldseperate[0]+'" class="form-control getupdateinputs getinputdata'+currentItem+'" data-knownid="'+currentItem+'" value="'+fieldseperate[1]+'"><p class="form-error mtabs"></p></div>';
  })

  $("#fieldallow").html(buildfields);

  $("#navPrev").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("#navNext").removeAttr("disabled");

  if (currentItem == 1) {
    $("#navPrev").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  else if (currentItem == data.length) {
    $("#navNext").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}

function openModal(idx) {

  currentItem = idx;
  loadData();
  $("#modal").modal();
}
  </script>
```

I tried but it will update to all object How can I fix this?
Is there Any Other way to solve? 
I tried like this also data[index].inputobjarr[nametochange] = "some update";

It will affect the Whole object

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: How are you creating data object? Is data object an array or JSON?

Comment: Its a Array only @Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: [{id:1, inputobjarr:{accordionid:"accordionid||1", parentdivclass:"parentdivclass||col-md-12 form-inline cust-align", type:"type||text", 'lablename-class':"lablename-class||col-md-2 heading form-group", lablename:"lablename||", tablerowhideflag:"tablerowhideflag||0", placeholder:"placeholder||"}}]

Comment: It would be good if you share the relevant HTML and try to reproduce this issue on code snippet

Comment: Its too long ..better u can hard code that and use this same array

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get object index first and then trying to update it but your logic is wrong and hence you are not getting the exact object to update.

Try below code where you can iterate the `data`object to get the object with matching id and update it inside loop instead of getting index first and then update.

```js
$(function(){
  var data = [{id:1, inputobjarr:{accordionid:"accordionid||1", parentdivclass:"parentdivclass||col-md-12 form-inline cust-align", type:"type||text", 'lablename-class':"lablename-class||col-md-2 heading form-group", lablename:"lablename||", tablerowhideflag:"tablerowhideflag||0", placeholder:"placeholder||"}},{id:2, inputobjarr:{accordionid:"accordionid||1", parentdivclass:"parentdivclass||col-md-12 form-inline cust-align", type:"type||text", 'lablename-class':"lablename-class||col-md-2 heading form-group", lablename:"lablename||", tablerowhideflag:"tablerowhideflag||0", placeholder:"placeholder||"}},{id:3, inputobjarr:{accordionid:"accordionid||1", parentdivclass:"parentdivclass||col-md-12 form-inline cust-align", type:"type||text", 'lablename-class':"lablename-class||col-md-2 heading form-group", lablename:"lablename||", tablerowhideflag:"tablerowhideflag||0", placeholder:"placeholder||"}}];
  $("body").on('keyup','.getupdateinputs',function(e) { 
    var inputid = $(this).data('knownid');
    var nametochange = $(this).attr('id');
    var changevalue = $(this).val();

    $.each(data, function(key, value){
       var id = value.id;
       if(id == inputid) {
          var obj = value.inputobjarr;
          obj[nametochange] = nametochange+'||'+changevalue;
       }
    });
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="getupdateinputs" id="1" data-knownid="1"><br/>
<input class="getupdateinputs" id="2" data-knownid="2"><br/>
<input class="getupdateinputs" id="3" data-knownid="3"><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur code i tried this code now .. It is also reflected whole object and one small suggestion <input class="getupdateinputs" id="accordionid" data-knownid="1"> input id set as a object index

Comment: I have put HTML as per my understanding, that is the reason i already asked you to post relevant HTML while asking question :)